# Natbib: maximum number of authors in bibliography

Tags: latex, bibtex, author, bibliography

I am using natbib to set up the bibliography in a latex document.
I would like citations to appear in the text as:

Author 1 et al., 2022

In the bibliography, I would like the citation to appear with a maximum of three authors. For example:

Author 1, Author 2, Author 3, et al. 2022, journal, page, number

I am currently using:

```
\usepackage[]{natbib}

...

...

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\bibliography{literatur}
```

which writes the citation as I want, but writes all the authors in the bibliography.

Is there a simple way to have max three authors in the bibliography with natbib?
Or possible alternatives with bibtex?

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127705/natbib-how-to-display-partial-authors-in-reference

Comment: If you would consider switching to biblatex, this would be much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Here an alternative using `biblatex` (make sure to compile with biber instead of bibtex)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,minbibnames=3,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{murray}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]